# When page resizes content boxes aren't centred anymore

Tags: html, css

The content boxes look good when they're full size, but when the page shrinks they are no longer centred. I've tried messing around with a bunch of things but can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong.

I've only been learning to code for a few weeks to please be kind lol, however if you have any off topic tips they are also appreciated

```css
        * {margin: 0; padding: 0}

        main {

            margin: 35px 50px;
            padding: 0px 15px;

        }

        .mainContent {

            display:block;
            height:auto;
            width: 60%;
            float:left;
            background-color: rgba(29,1,52,1);
            padding: 30px;
            color: #01b3ff;
            text-align:center;
        }


        .newsHolder {

            display: block;
            height:auto;
            width: 30%;
            float:right;
            background-color: rgba(29,1,52,1);
            padding: 20px 15px;
            color: #01b3ff;
        }

        .newsHolder img {

            float:left;
            padding: 15px;
        }


        @media screen and (min-width: 1141px) {

            .mainContent {

                margin-right: 10px;


            }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 1140px) {

            .mainContent {

                width: 100%;
                margin-bottom: 40px;
                clear:both;

            }

            .newsHolder {

                width:100%;
                clear:both;
                
            }
            
        }
```

```html
<body>

    <main>

        <div class="mainContent">

            <h1> Welcome to my website! </h1><br>
            <br>
            <p> 
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis laoreet eros. Sed tristique felis quis turpis aliquet, sed hendrerit massa tincidunt. Phasellus consequat finibus lectus id euismod. Sed orci nunc, tempus id condimentum vitae, pharetra ultrices nibh. Quisque erat ipsum, aliquam vitae pretium ac, consequat at nisi. Pellentesque vehicula, neque ac varius aliquam, lectus nisi sodales ante, bibendum lobortis justo metus nec sem. Duis a imperdiet lectus, ut interdum enim. Quisque eu commodo elit. Mauris massa lorem, ullamcorper luctus diam quis, lacinia lobortis arcu. Vestibulum facilisis feugiat nisl, eget tempus erat tempor sed. 
            </p>

        </div>


        <div class="newsHolder">

            <h1 style="text-align: center;"> BREAKING NEWS </h1><br>
            <br>

            
            <img src="images\angryluke.png">
            <h2> Lorem ipsum </h2>
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis laoreet eros. </p>

        </div>

    </main>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read more about **box-sizing**, just add `box-sizing: border-box;` to all elements and it will fix your problem.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
 main {
     margin: 35px 50px;
     padding: 0px 15px;
}
 .mainContent {
     display:block;
     height:auto;
     width: 60%;
     float:left;
     background-color: rgba(29,1,52,1);
     padding: 30px;
     color: #01b3ff;
     text-align:center;
}
 .newsHolder {
     display: block;
     height:auto;
     width: 30%;
     float:right;
     background-color: rgba(29,1,52,1);
     padding: 20px 15px;
     color: #01b3ff;
}
 .newsHolder img {
     float:left;
     padding: 15px;
}
 @media screen and (min-width: 1141px) {
     .mainContent {
         margin-right: 10px;
    }
}
 @media screen and (max-width: 1140px) {
     .mainContent {
         width: 100%;
         margin-bottom: 40px;
         clear:both;
    }
     .newsHolder {
         width:100%;
         clear:both;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="mainContent">
            <h1> Welcome to my website! </h1><br>
            <br>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis laoreet eros. Sed tristique felis quis turpis aliquet, sed hendrerit massa tincidunt. Phasellus consequat finibus lectus id euismod. Sed orci nunc, tempus id condimentum vitae, pharetra
                ultrices nibh. Quisque erat ipsum, aliquam vitae pretium ac, consequat at nisi. Pellentesque vehicula, neque ac varius aliquam, lectus nisi sodales ante, bibendum lobortis justo metus nec sem. Duis a imperdiet lectus, ut interdum enim.
                Quisque eu commodo elit. Mauris massa lorem, ullamcorper luctus diam quis, lacinia lobortis arcu. Vestibulum facilisis feugiat nisl, eget tempus erat tempor sed.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="newsHolder">
            <h1 style="text-align: center;"> BREAKING NEWS </h1><br>
            <br>
            <img src="images\angryluke.png">
            <h2> Lorem ipsum </h2>
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis laoreet eros. </p>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

Here is a link where you could know more about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing